# printf error on printing unsigned char

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the value of an unsigned char, but I'm getting an error for the printf of the code below. I want to combine the two values together later and output the combined bytes into decimal. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

```
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(512);
unsigned char first_byte = buffer[11];
unsigned char second_byte = buffer[12];
printf(%u, first_byte);
```

Comment: Put the format specifier within __quotes__.

Comment: And before continuing: **read a good C book. And pay attention while reading.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `printf()` is a string. You've written the "naked" symbols `%u` there, which is not a string.

You need to make it a string literal:

```
printf("%u", (unsigned int) first_byte);
```

The cast is to make sure the proper type gets passed, to make it clear that a conversion is needed since `%u` expects type `unsigned int` but you want to call with `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`%hhu`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)  as conversion specifier for unsigned 8-bit integers (`unsigned char`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char c1 = '*'; /* The ASCII value for '*' is 42. */
  unsigned char c2 = 255;

  printf("%hhu %hhu\n", c1, c2);

  return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
42 255
```